# reply emails are bounced due to URL in content

Tags: email, spam, false-positive

I have a client who communicates with me via email. Crazy, I know.

Here is the issue: When I send him an email from Mac Mail — *with my URL in the footer* – he receives it. However, when he tries to **reply** from his gmail account, my server bounces it back to him. The error is "554 rejected due to spam content". (a false-positive)

I can not collect the Spam Checker data from his email headers, as he is not tech savvy. I can not duplicate the error using a gmail account of my own. I have eliminated all possible problems, except the URL in my footer, which triggers this every time.

My email server is: 01-ah-r28u33-ss05.alphahosting.com

His gmail server is: mail-ob0-f172.google.com

Both of these (and also my test gmail server) are shared servers and have some blacklist reports. However, I have no such problems from other clients. My concern is that this could be a **reporting** problem, and I am failing to hear from those who would rather delete my email than give me a call. I think that you can understand my concern.

Please help, and do let me know if you need any other data that I might add in here.

Comment: If you can't reproduce the error by yourself, how do you know then, that it's just your footer URL?

Comment: Carston: By careful and exacting process of elimination.

Comment: So, when you send an email with just that footer URL from a gmail account to your business account, it gets blocked?

Comment: Good question, Carston. Sorry to not be clear: it is *any* URL that triggers the error. It just so happens that *my* email contains a URL (to my website) which is then included in his replies.

Comment: I have also whitelisted his email in my SpamAssassin settings, but his emails to me still bounce.

Comment: Any chance to get the complete header entry for the "554" (it usually says, who triggers the blocking)? Do you have any other rules in your SA config? If 'yes' then disable them and check again. If 'not', open a support ticket with your provider.

Comment: I'm tracking down the header info. This chap is genial, but a real luddite. I will post the progress here. Thanks again.